# Verify k-lite codec windows 10 file SHA256

Tags: codec, kleopatra

I'm trying to verify the k-lite codec I downloaded to my WINDOWS 10 laptop.
The site lists the .exe file to download with a link and lists the md5 and sha256 hashes. I'm trying to verify the hashes with kleopatra(or anything really).

1. In kleopatra I try to verify the .exe file, but the error, "could not determine if this is a s/mime or OpenPGP sig at all?" If I've downloaded the .exe file, shouldn't the hashes be INCLUDED in the file?
2. Or am I supposed to copy the sha256 hash and create a new .asc file to check?
   here is the download webpage
   [enter link description here](https://codecguide.com/klcp_update.htm)

Thanks for any help

Comment: A hash is not a signature, so PGP and Kleopatra are the wring tools. You just need a hash tool, e.g. on command-line or for Windows Explorer like https://github.com/namazso/OpenHashTab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to verify the hashes with kleopatra(or anything really)

I assume you have windows as the file is an `exe`. Try using Powershell to get the file's hash

```ps
Get-FileHash C:\path\to\your_file -Algorithm SHA256 | select hash
```

where `C:\path\to\your_file` is the path to your file.

This is the output after downloading and checking the hash:

```ps
PS C:\Downloads\Programs> Get-FileHash "kl*" -Algorithm SHA256 | select hash

Hash
----
C62ADDBEA3CC244020B7B587838F9E65A2F8B4FE31252C1B34B0F8EEAF6D7FC6
```

which is the hash listed on the linked page.

[image: SHA256 hash of the file as shown on the linked page]

Comment: damn homey! Ok, looks like it verified. Hmmm...this seems a lot more easier than using kleopatra. Many thanks!